# Update db with new fields

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called `example`

```
example = new Mongo.Collection("example");
```

`example` contains a variety of different fields I would like to update, however while updating I would also like to include new fields.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documents it is possible.

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/set/

> If the field does not exist, $set will add a new field with the
>   specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type
>   constraint.

```
      example.update(exampleId, {
        $set: {
         newfield: "new field information",
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

Update:-

If an update operation with upsert: true results in an insert of a document, then $setOnInsert assigns the specified values to the fields in the document. If the update operation does not result in an insert, $setOnInsert does nothing.

You can specify the upsert option for either the db.collection.update() or db.collection.findAndModify() methods.

```html
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   { $setOnInsert: { <field1>: <value1>, <field2>: <value2>,... } },
   { upsert: true }
)
```